# Mandate integer type in django-rest-framework validator for integerfield

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

django-rest-framework validator accepts string quoted integers as valid data for  integer field. Is there a way to mandate data type so that string quoted integers won't be accepted ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Serializer keeps raw data in `self.initial_data` from where custom validation methods can retrieve it. So the following works

```py
class Test(Serializer):
  true_int = IntegerField()

  def validate_true_int(self, value):
    value = self.initial_data.get('true_int')
    if isinstance(value, int):
      return value
    raise ValidationError("Not an int")


data = {'true_int': '10'}
t = Test(data=data)
t.is_valid()  # false

data = {'true_int': 10}
t = Test(data=data)
t.is_valid() # true
```

Answer (score 0):

<strike>You can add a custom validator to the field.
[Custom Validator](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/validators/#function-based)</strike>

You can create a custom serializer field that errors before conversion to an integer.

```py
class TrueIntegerField(serializers.IntegerField):
    def to_internal_value(self, data):
        if isinstance(data, six.text_type):
            raise serializers.ValidationError("Value should be an integer")
        return super().to_internal_value(data)
```

Comment: drf converts argument passed to custom validator and will be an integer for integer field. that wont work in this case.

Comment: Oh, you're right. Your best bet is to extend the IntegerField

Answer (score 0):

You can write field validation

```
def validate_field_name(self):
    validating_data = self.context.get('request').data.get('field_name')
    if isinstance(validating_data, int):
        return validating_data
    raise ValidationError('Integer value required')
```

Comment: drf converts argument passed to custom validator and will be an integer for integer field. that wont work in this case

Comment: DRF converts the data but we take the data from the request which is in the actual form.

Comment: This is applicable to a particular case. There need not be a context always.

Comment: Without context how we pass data? If there is a request there will be context.

Comment: try the code in the above answer. there is no context there.