# How to throw back serializer.errors in Django?

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

How do I throw the `serializer.errors` if I have a wrong input in some field? Do I have to code some "logic", or I just have to write some "configurations".

```
#models.py
class Product(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField()
    amount = models.IntegerField()
    description = models.TextField()

#serializers.py
class ProductSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Product
        fields = '__all__'
    def create(self, validated_data):
        ...
    def update(self, instance, validated_data):
        ...

#views.py
class ProductViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    serializer_class = ProductSerializer

    def partial_update(self, request, pk=None):
        ...

    def get_queryset(self):
        ...
```

For example I want to POST:

```
{
"name": "Banana",
"amount": "ABCD",
"description": ""
}
```

Instead of getting an error in the server:

```
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'ABCD'
```

I want a response like this:

```
{"amount": ["A valid integer is required."], "description": ["This field may not be blank."]}
```

Comment: As per the Model structure, DRF will take care of the ***basic validations***. If you want more detailed validations, use **`validate()`** method

Comment: How do you "configure" the basic validations? How is it not returned to me?

Comment: I don't have `def create()` in my view.

Comment: your views seem fine, can you add full error traceback?

Comment: It is an error since I don't have a valid input for the IntegerField()

Comment: `/django/db/models/fields/__init__.py", line 1825, in get_prep_value
    return int(value)
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'ABCD'
`

Comment: I said "full error traceback"

Comment: I got a full developed app. That is just an example and a snippet of what is going on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far the model is designed, the `modelserializer` will take care. In case you want more control of validation in your hand then you can do it in your `serializers`. For your problem, the following snippets would work.

```py
#serializers.py

class ProductSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Product
        fields = '__all__'

    def create(self, validated_data):
        ...

    def update(self, instance, validated_data):
        ...

    def validate(self, attrs):
        # you can add your validation rule here 
        if not isinstance(attrs.get('amount'), int):
            serializers.ValidationError({
                "amount": ["A valid integer is required."],
                "description": ["This field may not be blank."]
            })
```

In this way, you can use `validate()` to validate any field of your serializer as you wish. [Official documentation on validator in serializer](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/validators/), Also you can use `validate_<field_name>(self, <field_name>)` function to validate a specific field of a serializer. Like mentioned in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54784205/9246099).

Comment: How do you "activate" the "default" validations?

Comment: default validation will get in the action by default when you use `model serializer`. By explicitly defining the `validate()` you can add extra validations for the serializer's fields.

Comment: When I pass a `str` for example a `IntegerField()`. I get an error in server, and no response is sent back...